# How many VM's we can connect to Azure File Share?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-files, azure-storage-files

I have gone through the documentation of [Azure file share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-introduction).

But didn't found how many VM's we can connect to this file share.

Is it unlimited?

Answer (score 0):

```
How many VM's we can connect to Azure File Share?
```

Yes, it is unlimited and any number of Azure Virtual Machines or roles can mount and connect to Azure File Share simultaneously.

Azure files provide shared access across multiple virtual machines.